# Como agrego HTML JAVASCRIPT Y Jquery en React

Tags: reactjs

Quiero agregar una  libreria para carrousel que encontre pero tengo los archivos html,css javascript por aparte, como podria hacer para integrarlo en React y que funcione.

esta es la libreria:

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

no coloco codigo porque aun no he intentado nada, no tengo idea como hacerlo.

quiero lograr este efecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se trabaja con React no se aconseja hacer uso de librerías que manipulen el DOM como jQuery, esto porque la manipulación del DOM es responsabilidad de React y puede desencadenar bugs difíciles de debuggear. Es un requerimiento mandatorio usar esa librería que comentas? Yo tengo otra que te puedo recomendar ampliamente, avísame si te sirve.

Link: https://swiperjs.com/react

Saludos,

JuanCa -> https://www.twitter.com/jcrengifoa

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario, quisiera lograr el efecto de la imagen donde aparezcan 3 tarjetas, con esa libreria podria lograr algo así?

Comment: Si puedes!, la prop slidesPerView es exactamente para eso, con eso le pasas el número de tarjetas que quieres por paso del slider/carrusel. De nada, estamos para ayudarnos :)

Answer (score 0):

En react no es recomendable usar otras librerias como JQuery, en este caso que encontraste un Carousel para HTML, es mejor buscar librerias que hagan lo mismo para react, asi te evitas pasar el codigo que encontraste a JSX.

Aqui te dejo una pagina con librerias para mostrar imagenes:

https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-react-carousel-libraries

Espero te sirva amigo. Saludos.